# Spring Boot + Flyway + Testcontainers(mariaDB): Table "xxxx" doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, junit4, flyway, testcontainers

I use Testcontainers with mariaDB database in a Spring Boot project for unit testing. I recently upgraded Spring Boot from 2.4.4 to 2.6.6 and found out that the unit test started to fail. The Testcontainers was created again (?) after the Flyway migration  happened (which created the database schema).

I am slightly confused and wonder whether there are specific configuration that needs to be set to make the unit test work again.

Dependencies are as below

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "8.4.2"
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    testCompileOnly 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.2'
    implementation  "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.1.0"
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.4'
    implementation "org.jooq:jooq:3.16.5"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mariadb:1.16.2"
    ....
```

Configuration is as below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mariadb:10.5:///
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.datasource.username=""
spring.datasource.password=""

spring.jooq.sql-dialect=MARIADB

spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/migration
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:tc:mariadb:10.5:///
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

# logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Log message is as below

```
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] c.a.a.m.r.MyUnitTest   : Starting MyUnitTest using Java 11.0.11 on xxxxxxx with PID 49309 (started by user.name in /Volumes/code/sample/sample)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] c.a.a.m.r.MyUnitTest   : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration' of type [io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.async.DefaultAsyncAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e8860ae] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
WARN 49309 --- [    Test worker] i.o.c.s.t.c.TracerAutoConfiguration      : Tracer bean is not configured! Switching to NoopTracer
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.c.s.w.s.ServerTracingAutoConfiguration : Creating WebMvcConfigurer bean with class io.opentracing.contrib.spring.web.interceptor.TracingHandlerInterceptor
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.t.utility.ImageNameSubstitutor         : Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Docker host IP address is localhost
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 20.10.13
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7859 MB
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.t.utility.RegistryAuthLocator          : Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for index.docker.io
2022-05-16 09:18:36.309  INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.t.utility.RyukResourceReaper           : Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Checking the system...
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Creating container for image: mariadb:10.5
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 is starting: 57036754c74fbb2440acd1f1796bc5cc6b8e5ba3e303b73e53ed666ebee34b18
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51394/test using query 'SELECT 1'
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51394/test)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 started in PT6.247538S
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 8.2.0 by Redgate
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51394/test (MariaDB 10.5)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Successfully dropped pre-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.003s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Successfully cleaned schema `test` (execution time 00:00.013s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Successfully cleaned schema `test` (execution time 00:00.013s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbClean        : Successfully dropped post-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.002s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Creating container for image: mariadb:10.5
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 is starting: 1dfd0cd43d1d842ded36f12f7081fcaedc3768ff8dae2514a7ad8c3fba4a9bf6
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51457/test using query 'SELECT 1'
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51457/test)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 started in PT6.413163S
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 8.2.0 by Redgate
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.016s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table `test`.`flyway_schema_history` ...
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema `test`: << Empty Schema >>
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `test` to version "1.0 - create db schema"
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `test` to version "1.1 - remove bad entries"
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `test` to version "1.2 - remove old entries"
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 3 migrations to schema `test`, now at version v1.2 (execution time 00:00.127s)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will not secure any request
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log               : Logging initialized @20593ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Creating container for image: mariadb:10.5
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 is starting: 51aa6eb7e010bddd69d9e906cbc97cff242bd46a3d85a9d08dc1b85e6a35b70a
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51525/test using query 'SELECT 1'
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51525/test)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker]  [mariadb:10.5]                        : Container mariadb:10.5 started in PT6.344117S
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost:51525/test?user=test&password=***'
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.c.s.w.s.ServerTracingAutoConfiguration : Creating FilterRegistrationBean bean with TracingFilter mapped to [], skip pattern is "/api-docs.*|/swagger.*|.*\.png|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.html|/favicon.ico|/hystrix.stream|/actuator/(health|health/.*)"
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] c.a.a.m.r.MyUnitTest   : Started MyUnitTest in 27.52 seconds (JVM running for 28.705)
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@6b41f56a testClass = MyUnitTest, testInstance = com.demo.sample.process.repository.MyUnitTest@55c989d7, testMethod = testProcess@MyUnitTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6b04eb82 testClass = MyUnitTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.sample.sampleApplication, class com.demo.sample.process.config.TestAppConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:application-integration.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@775b1965, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@121f6d87, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@773ce2e2, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4b69c0cb, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@411029bf, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@7aa81bef], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager@2da8b79d]; rollback [true]
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.jooq.Constants                       : 
                                      
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@  @  @  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Thank you for using jOOQ 3.15.1
                                      
INFO 49309 --- [    Test worker] org.jooq.Constants                       : 

jOOQ tip of the day: While you don't have to use jOOQ's code generator, there are *lots* of awesome features you're missing out on if you're not using it!

WARN 49309 --- [    Test worker] o.m.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket      : Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'test.my_db_table' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly changed between SpringBoot `2.4` and `2.6`, but I think you need to remove `spring.flyway.url` property at all. I can only guess that the property was ignored by the older SpringBoot for some reason.

Once you remove the property, Flyway will use the `spring.datasource.url` value and only one MariaDB container will be started by Testcontainers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are abosolutely correct on the "remove `spring.flyway.url` property" part.

Unit tests work properly after removing `spring.flyway.[url,user,password]` in external properties.

Here are some details mentioned in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) 85.5.1 Execute Flyway Database Migrations on Startup